# Esthetic How To Reverse Quotes

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I am almost done with my project finally and im not sure how secure it really is but its a jumping off point and will see if the site ever gets any traffic if so many ill pay to have someone fix some things other wise it can wait while I keep learning but long story short I have it outputing a file

And I am having a bit of trouble with it.

here is my code

```
 file_put_contents('DONE.html', '<html><?php include('config.php'); </html>');
```

But as im sure you can see my issue is that since this whole string is put into ' quotes it dosnt read the config.php correctly because it thinks it should be out of quotes how do I fix this cause I have a ton of ' And " that need to be added to this and im not sure how to make my php script out put quotes.

Comment: Are you trying to output your `config.php` into `DONE.html` surrounding it by HTML tags, or are you trying to add `<html><?php include('config.php'); ?></html>` to a file? Either way, unless you have PHP setup to process HTML files too, then all it will do is render `<?php include('config.php'); ?>` as text (and incorrectly since you do not have a body tag)

Comment: The most confusing part of the question is the "esthetic" bit, as if the code is already working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote characters in strings delimited by the same character should be escaped with a reverse solidus / backslash character.

```
 file_put_contents('DONE.html', '<html><?php include(\'config.php\'); </html>');
```

Comment: I mean is it only me, or in fact this whole technique is unbelievably prone to errors. So you create a file `done.html` and then put `<?php` and raw `</html>` side by side, how on earth can that be good?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want to do:

```
 file_put_contents('DONE.html', "<html><?php include('config.php'); </html>");

 file_put_contents('DONE.html', '<html><?php include("config.php"); </html>');

 file_put_contents('DONE.html', "<html><?php include(\"config.php\"); </html>");
```

You basically alternate between single and double quotes, or escape (with backslash ) the double quotes within double quotes so it doesn't close the previous one.

Anyway I think what you want to do is kind of strange. Instead of adding the include into that file, why don't you just include the config.php directly? what happens if you change the config.php's name or path? You would have to change it from all the files, why don't just:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("DONE.html");
?>
```